# How to deploy phone app dependent android wear apps?

Tags: android, deployment, wear-os

I want to deploy this App (https://github.com/pocmo/SensorDashboard) on my Phone and Wearable. Deploying the App on my Phone works fine. When I try to deploy the App on my watch like I deploy it on my Phone, I get the following Error: *Error running wear: Default Activity not found*.
I think that this Error is caused by the fact, that the App isn't a *Standalone Wearable App* and can't be deployed by selecting a deployment target as you would with a phone . When I look in the AndroidManifest.xml the meta-data tag looks like this:

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

How can I deploy this App on my watch?

(I want to know how the deployment works manually and I don't want to download the App from the Play Store)

Answer (score 0):

The project has no activity because it's a service. In such a Project one has to go in Android Studio under Run/Edit Configurations -> General -> Launch -> select the option "Nothing". After this the app can be deployed on the watch by selecting a deployment target as you would with a phone.